# Help diagnose Z-banding

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, monoprice-select-mini

The printer is ["Monoprice MP Select Mini 3D Printer V2"](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=21711).

This is how my printed fan part looks like:

[image: Printed fan part]

These printers are notorious for their Z lead screw assembly (M4 bolt & nut) so I installed flex coupler and aligned the M4 bolt and motor shaft so that the wobble is minimal. It is still there, but I don't think this amount of wobble would produce something like what I experience. Please check out the [timelapse video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/XTdaZMjGvCgwsZ9W7) at the end.

I also tightened up Z guide rails (no rattle, very little slop)

Moreover the banding appears to be less pronounced and have alot greater period for vase prints [image: Vase print; extruded ellipse printed along Y axis]

(this is extruded ellipse printed along Y axis).
I tried:

1. slowing down print by 50 % - no effect on banding.
2. monitored hotend temperature with external probe on the heater block (-+5 °C)

The banding appears to be almost exclusively in Y axis direction; for example, the same ellipse printed along X axis: 
[image: Vase print; extruded ellipse printed along X axis]

Now, same ellipse in layered mode (seam side) printed along Y axis
[image: Layered print; extruded ellipse printed along Y axis]

Comment: Please put photos in your question, not as links to external sites.

Comment: Do you know the lead screw's lead/pitch? What is your layer height? Made any calibration adjustments to steps-per-mm?

Comment: the lead screw is just M4 so i guess the pitch is 0.7 (according to http://www.metrication.com/engineering/threads.html ) and layer height is 0.3063. Didn't do any calibration adjustments.

Comment: it would help if we would know the model - is it a perfect cylinder or can you show it? Also, this is a cantilever printer, make sure that the arm does not raise or lower during printing.

Comment: @0scar: How does 0.7×200 come up? If the pitch is 0.7 and there are 200 steps, it should be 0.7/200×200=0.7, not 0.7×200. But I'm skeptical that the pitch is actually 0.7. Does M4 mean actual M4 thread in this context, or just 4mm diameter with a metric thread profile shape but some larger pitch and possibly multiple starts?

Comment: It looks like the period is 14-15 layers, which would be 4.2882-4.5945 mm based on the above-reported layer height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This differs from the traditional banding as observed from Z wobble induced banding as e.g. explained in [this answer](/a/5824).

Your banding patterns clearly seem to form diagonal bands, this is most probably a combination of the lead and the full rotation of the stepper. The most logical explanation is that the layer shifts as a whole in X-Y direction (when seen against the print height, this movement is concentric seen from the top). This means that the next layer is positioned over the previous layer in a concentric pattern. This hints to some sort of defect in your X/Y-plane assembly and should be investigated further.

This is difficult to visualize, but this sketch shows the issue for some layers:

[image: Diagonal Z banding by concentric consecutive offsets]

This could be related to the belts of the X and Y-axis, play on the drive pulleys, non-straight lead screw, guide rods with play, play in general, [Z-stepper alignment to the threaded rod](https://hackaday.io/project/14823-monoprice-select-mini-maximum-3d-printer-mods/log/51880-dont-go-wobbly-on-me-now), etc. Considering the amount of [Z-wobble fixes](https://www.mpselectmini.com/thingiverse/z-axis-stabilizers) shared by the unofficial MP Select Wiki, the best place to look for is the Z-stepper to lead screw coupling.

Comment: It sounds like the lead screw might be bent (thus applying forces in the X and Y directions dependent on its rotational orientation) and like the Y axis belt may have more play/elasticity in it (or X if I read the description backwards).

Comment: Thank you @0scar! I think your diagnosis is spot on. I checked slop and belts on Y axis before but didn't consider that bed heating cable might snag underneath the rails thus impeding proper Y positioning. I wouldn't expect this effect to have periodic rather than random effect though. but the issue is almost gone after repositioning of the cable.